# Semicolon expected using an underscore in an int

Tags: java, syntax

For an application program, I'm attempting to initialize an int variable to 3_745_000. However, at any point I try to compile, I am given the ';' expected error at the first underscore used, and the identifier expected error at the actual semi colon. As far as I know, this is an entirely legal use of an underscore in Java, so I don't understand why I'm receiving the error. This is the code.

```
private static int lastacct = 3_745_000;
```

I am given the same error no matter where I try to put the underscore.

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: Use Java 7 or 8, problem solved.

Comment: I'm currently using the recommended version of Java, Java 8, and using the jGRASP compiler to write my application. The compiler is up to date as well.

Comment: Then we're going to see more code and need more info because it should work. Are you using an IDE? If so, which one? How are you compiling?

Comment: If you execute `java -version` on the console, do you get 1.8 as well? Do you have any compiler flags set in jGRASP? Are you using a different language level?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the variable you made is an instance variable,make sure it is not placed inside any of your methods,just inside the class.